# How to create a software that can be used as a browser extension in python?

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-api, browser-extension, browser-plugin

I have written a python program to download YouTube videos. I want to add it as an extension to browser, but I have read that browser doesn't run python scripts. So how can I deploy it? Can I convert it into a software which when installed can be added as a plug-in to the browser? Or is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
You should supply a sample of your code and show what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are aware of the chrome extension/plugin development, If not, please go through online tutorials,  Fast forward...

Adding Python to the Chrome extension
We have two options to add Python into a chrome extension:

**Method 1:** Include

> Brython

in an iframe (requires server)
To run Python in the browser you have several options including Brython and emcascripten.

*Method 2:* Compile Python to Javascript using

> Rapydscript

(best, serverless, pure extension.)
There are several tools to compile Python to Javascript. Rapydscript works fine, Pyjs does not work well with chrome.

Further, you can do your research.

Comment: @Raj Vichare does this helped you in any way?